# Jquery draggable inside of niceScroll plugin overflow issue

Tags: jquery, overflow, draggable, droppable, nicescroll

Hi I have a list of items that are draggable that need dropped onto a different div.

I am using the jquery plugin niceScroll and I can't drag objects 'outside' of the niceScroll and I think has something to do with overflow being hiddent but cannot make it work.

The drop event fires when I let go of the mouse over the droppable div.

I have

```
//COMMENT ME OUT TO SEE THAT IT WORKS WHEN niceScroll IS NOT ENABLED
$("#external-sales-orders").niceScroll();

$(".external-event").draggable({
    revert: true

});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(){
        alert("Dropped");
    }
});
```

check out this : http://jsfiddle.net/BYK4J/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a clone and appending it to the `body`:

```
$(".external-event").draggable({
    revert: true,
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BYK4J/4/)

Check out the appendTo() documentation: [JQuery UI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo).

AppendTo designates which element the draggable helper should be appended to while dragging. By default this is set to the elements parent.

**UPDATE:**

Figured out a way to achieve the functionality you wanted in congruence with the nice scroll plugin. When the element is dragged it sets the original element to `visibility:hidden` so the spot is still preserved and then when the item is dropped it reverts the `visibility`. Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYK4J/6/).

Comment: I did try that, but I don't want the copy, I want it to react the same way that it does without niceScroll enabled if possible. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Ah, I see. You could override the `overflow:hidden` that niceScroll puts on the container div, but that kind of defeats the purpose of the plugin (http://jsfiddle.net/BYK4J/5/)

Comment: @kevindstanley Updated my answer with the functionality you were looking for.